# Kafka KSQLDB - Computing a input formula

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am using Kafka KsqlDB.
I'm trying to make a simple filter of a Table (for example, SELECT * FROM table WHERE formula). The problem is that the filter formula is on the input data (CSV file data from Kafka Connect). So the main point of this problem is to use a formula that is external to KsqlDB and then putting that formula inside the WHERE clause. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understood your question.
If I did, the suggestion for you would be that you might use DropFilter SMT with setting ksql source connector on the CSV file.